# Plot a number-line graph in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

I have dataset consisting of 2 columns, one is a factor and the other contains mean scores for each factor level.
I want to create a number line graph where the factor labels can be shown on the graph along the number line which can either be horizontal or vertical. e.g.
[image: Sample Graph]
Update:
I tested my actual data with the code provided in the answer the following result.

Data:

```
Category    dim1
Academic    -20.0285
AdminWrit   -24.262
BInd.   1.343235294
BNews   -5.69675
BRDDiss 11.981
BRDInt  14.639
BRDNws  -16.9715
BRDTlks 7.953
BssLett -22.146
BTech   -10.824
ClsLessons  3.5675
Comments    8.92779661
Comntry -0.941
Dem/Doc -7.176
Editorial   -14.969
ExmScript   -11.881
F2FConv 12.89844444
FBGroups    14.20809091
FBStatus    5.1265
Leg/ThsPrs  -13.772
N-BRDTlks   -1.532
Novel   -3.556
NwsRep  -14.25
Par/PolDeb  3.971111111
Popular -9.94925
Reprtage    -19.255
Sh-Story    1.363
SkillHob    -8.903
SocLett -10.63133333
Speech  -1.215666667
StdntEssy   -7.786
Tweets  9.68675
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: `ggplot(data, aes(x=Score)) + geom_text(aes(y=Category))+coord_flip()`?

Comment: Unfortunately my knowledge is very limited and I start to write (=copy paste) some code in R by looking at similar code snippets already available online. And I could not find anything in this regard that is why I had to ask.

Answer (score 3):

You can try something else (your table should be named `d`):

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(d) +
    geom_text(aes(-1, Score, label = Score)) +
    geom_text(aes(1, Score, label = Category)) +
    geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype = 4) +
    coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-5, 5)) +
    labs(x = NULL,
         y = NULL) +
    theme_classic() +
    theme(axis.line.y = element_blank(),
          axis.ticks = element_blank(),
          axis.text = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks I will build on this example to make it better suited for my purpose.

Comment: But you've got to ask yourself at this point, what are you really gaining by using ggplot()? Might be just as easy using `grid` graphics alone. You still get my upvote.

Comment: @PoGibas This is a good approximation of what I want. I hope someone else can provide another solution that is a little more appropriate.

Comment: @MrFlick (if the comment was for me) I will look into base r solutions as well. Just that I am used to of (searching and finding answers for) ggplot2. The code snippets are readily available (normally).

Comment: @MuhammadShakirAziz what else do you need with the figure, I can help with that :-)

Comment: Please look at the plot result at the and of my first post. The text labels are overlapping. I think jitter() function in ggplot2 might be able to help, but I do not know if it would be able to force values on similar vertical level to form a horizontal line on that level. Or otherwise I think the factor levels having similar mean school should be together (after rounding the mean scores) and then plot them again.